# Oracle и Client на одной машине

Tags: oracle

Установил oracle 12 на машину, теперь хочу подключаться к БД и работать с ней в PL/SQL Developer. Для этого нужно устанавливать клиент оракл? или можно обойтись без него?

Comment: Нет, не надо, он уже установлен.

Comment: У меня проблемы. Я установил developer но он не видит БД и даже если вручную ввести выдает ошибку связанную с oci.dll

Comment: Initialization error
Could not initialize "C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll"
Make sure you have the 32 bits Oracle Client installed.

OCIDLL forced to C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll
LoadLibrary(C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oci.dll) returned 0

Comment: Читал тут https://o7planning.org/ru/10255/installing-and-configuring-pl-sql-developer похоже это распространенная ошибка и нужен клиент 32 битный?

Comment: Поставте 64-битного клиента.

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Я имел ввиду developer, у вас БД 64-бит и клиентская часть тоже. Можете для начала попробовать с sql-developer, он у вас уже стоит.

Comment: Получилось. Спасибо.